# Java String.codePointAt returns unexpected value

Tags: java, string, encoding

If I use any ASCII characters from 33 to 127, the `codePointAt` method gives the correct decimal value, for example:

```
String s1 = new String("#");
int val = s1.codePointAt(0);
```

This returns 35 which is the correct value.

But if I try use ASCII characters from 128 to 255 (extended ASCII/ISO-8859-1), this method gives wrong value, for example:

```
String s1 = new String("ƒ")  // Latin small letter f with hook
int val = s1.codePointAt(0);
```

This should return 159 as per [this reference table](http://www.asciitable.com), but instead returns 409, why is this?

Comment: Your reference table is very bad. It's called "Extended ASCII", which does not make much sense since there are myriads of different character sets that could all be called "Extended ASCII". It should at least state what character set it is about.

Comment: Look at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/192/index.htm for all information about ƒ. There you find information about which charsets and codepages support this characters.

Answer (score 5):

> But if I try use ASCII characters from 128 to 255

ASCII doesn't have values in this range. It only uses 7 bits.

Java chars are UTF-16 (and nothing else!). If you want to represent ASCII using Java, you need to use a byte array.

The `codePointAt` method returns the 32-bit codepoint. 16-bit chars can't contain the entire Unicode range, so some code points must be split across two chars (as per the [encoding scheme for UTF-16](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2781)). The `codePointAt` method helps resolve to chars code points.

I wrote a rough guide to encoding in Java [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html).

Answer (score 2):

Java chars are not encoded in ISO-8859-1. They use UTF-16 which has the same values for 7bit ASCII characters (only values from 0-127).

To get the correct value for ISO-8859-1 you have to convert your string into a byte[] with <strike>`String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");`</strike> and look in the byte array.

**Update**

ISO-8859-1 is not the [extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding, use `String.getBytes("Cp437");` to get the correct values.

Comment: 'ƒ' is not represented in ISO-8859-1, so the result of getBytes is undefined. On some implementations it will only return the bytes for '?'.

Comment: @Michael Konietzka good to know, I didn't check the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

in Unicode

```
ƒ 0x0192 LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.codePointAt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) returns the Unicode-Codepoint at this specified index.

The Unicode-Codepoint of ƒ is 402, see

http://www.decodeunicode.org/de/u+0192/properties

So

```
System.out.println("ƒ".codePointAt(0));
```

printing `402` is correct.

If you are interested in the representation in other charsets, you can printout the bytes representaion of the character in other charsets via [getBytes(String charsetName)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    final String s = "ƒ";
    for (final String csName : Charset.availableCharsets().keySet()) {
    try {
     final Charset cs = Charset.forName(csName);
     final CharsetEncoder encode = cs.newEncoder();
     if (encode.canEncode(s)) 
          {
      System.out.println(csName + ": " + Arrays.toString(s.getBytes(csName)));
          }
        } catch (final UnsupportedOperationException uoe) {
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     }
    }
```